# Workaround for reconnect-problems within Qt's namedpipe-implementation?

Tags: qt, named-pipes

I'm experiencing some variant of a bug described here (using the sample code in the bugreport):

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22145

It's reproducable like this:

- Start the application twice (now called App1 and App2)
- Click "listen" in App1
- Click "connect" in App2(you will see that the connection is established successfully on both sides)
- Click "ping" in App2 (you will see a "ping" message in App1 and a "pong" message in App2)
- Close app1 (you will see a disconnect-message in App2)
- Start another instance (now called App3)
- Click "listen" in App3
- Click "connect" in App2 (you will see that the connection is established successfully on both sides)
- Click "ping" in App2 (now neither a ping- nor a pong-message will be transmitted)

Is there any workaround known to get a working connection in that scenario?
Is there any way to detect that the connection isn't working?

PS: My Qt-project-file in addition to the VS-project-file in the bug-report:

> ```
> QT           += network gui
> HEADERS += \
>     mainwidget.h
> SOURCES += \
>     mainwidget.cpp \
>     main.cpp
> ```